# How can I list/know the available nodes in a package?

Tags: ros, package, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How do you list/know the available nodes to run using rosrun in a package???

Thanks.
--Luis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146411/how-can-i-list/know-the-available-nodes-in-a-package?/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just enter `rosrun package_name` in bash and press 2 times tab.... E. g. for image_view it gives:

```
~$ rosrun image_view 
disparity_view  extract_images  image_saver     image_view      stereo_view     video_recorder
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2